# OkHttpClient support for encoded special characters like %20(+) in query param

Tags: decode, okhttp, encode, apache-httpclient-4.x

We have upgraded our product from Apache HttpClient to OkHttpClient. But after migration, when special characters like %20(+) is passed in URL param or query param, its been sent to client as is, where it was decoded and sent to client with Apache HttpClient.

eg : http://ip:port/testURL?A%20B   -> http://ip:port/testURL?A+B  ( Apache HttpClient)
http://ip:port/testURL?A%20B   -> http://ip:port/testURL?A%20B ( OkHttpClient)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Comment: I have already encoded the special characters before dispatching the request to OkHttpClient, but still %20 is been sent as is and not encoded value. All other special characters are encoded expect %20.

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp attempts to preserve as much as possible on input URLs. If you want to convert parts to a canonical form, use HttpUrl.Builder and set each part independently, possibly using your original parsed HttpUrl as input.